# When the equations of motion are not unique (eg. when they are given by eigenvectors), which will the free particle adhere to?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, action, constrained-dynamics

For this question I think it will be easier to express the usual equation describing the motion of a "free particle,"--viz. $g_{ij}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j$--in matrix form as follows:

$$g_{ij}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j=\mathbf{\dot{x}'Q\dot{x}}$$

where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the metric tensor and the apostraphe indicates the transpose.

Now, given the constant velocity constraint $$\mathbf{\dot{x}'\dot{x}}=k$$ the integrand of the action becomes:

$$\mathbf{\dot{x}'Q\dot{x}}+\lambda(\mathbf{\dot{x}'\dot{x}}-k)$$

where $\lambda$ is a lagrangian multiplier.

Assuming a Cartesian metric (such that $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Q}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{0}$), the Euler Lagrange condition yields the following equations of motion:

$$2\mathbf{Q\ddot{x}}=\lambda\mathbf{\ddot{x}}$$

There is not one unique set of EoM that satisfy this equation but 4, i.e. one for each of the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{Q}$ (and their corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda$).

How am I to interpret the physics of such a result?  Which of the 4 solutions will the free particle adhere to?

Comment: 1. You've introduced the "constant velocity constraint", and you *have to impose it*, i.e. the Lagrange multiplier *also* gets an equation of motion through Euler-Lagrange, namely the constraint itself. 2. Shouldn't velocity *also* be measured with the metric tensor, i.e. constant velocity should be $\dot{x}^T Q \dot{x} = k$? 3. Using the constraint $\dot{x}^TQ \dot{x} = k$ and differentiating it again w.r.t. time and *then* using the e.o.m. for $x$ should give you a "better" equation.